# Having quotation marks as a character in a python list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

How do I put quotation marks in a list as an actual character?

Currently what I am doing is this:

```
pairings = ["A,#","B,6","C,+","D,""]
```

As you can see for 'D', I am making D equal to a quotation mark, however this is not possible as Python thinks it is an other value in a list. If I wanted to make D equal to " in this list how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings in python you can use both single and double quoatation marks, `'` and `"`. As such you can use one to have a string containing the other.

```
pairings = ['A,#','B,6','C,+','D,"']
```

I've modified all of the quotation marks to just use single, so it's consistent.

You can also escape quotation marks in strings using a backslash as below

```
s = 'This is my string, it contains a single quotation mark \', but that\'s fine because I\'ve escaped them!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slash before " 
I mean

```
"D,\" "
```

or

```
'D, " '
```

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 choces:

```
pairings = ['A,#','B,6','C,+','D,"']
```

or

```
pairings = ["A,#","B,6","C,+","D,\""]
```

In python you can placa String inside ' or " qotation characters. Or you can try to escape them.